# Function not returning the highest and lowest values entered into the array

Tags: c++, arrays, max, min

This function is not accurately returning the highest and lowest values entered into the array. I'm not sure what I code I entered for the program to do this. This program needs to return the average of all of the elements entered into the array (the average part works fine) as well as find the highest and lowest values among all of the values entered into the array. Please help!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
float temptotal = 0;
float averagetemp = 0;
float temperatures[50];
float average(int);
void highest(int);
void lowest(int);
int main()
{
int days = 0;
cout << "Enter the number of days: ";
cin >> days;
if (days > 50)
{
    cout << "You may only enter temperatures for 50 days." << endl;
    return 0;
}
average(days);
highest(days);
lowest(days);
}
float average(int days)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= days; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter the temperature for day number " << i << ": ";
        cin >> temperatures[i];
        temptotal += temperatures[i];
    }
        averagetemp = temptotal / days;
        cout << "The average temperature is: " << averagetemp << endl;
        return averagetemp;
}
void highest(int days)
{
    int count;
    int highest;
    highest = temperatures[50];
    for (count = 1; count < days; count++)
    {
        if (temperatures[count] > highest)
            highest = temperatures[count];
        cout << "The highest temperature is: " << highest << endl;
    }
}
void lowest(int days)
{
    int count;
    int lowest;
    lowest = temperatures[50];
    for (count = 1; count < days; count++)
    {
        if (temperatures[count] < lowest)
            lowest = temperatures[count];
        cout << "The lowest temperature is: " << lowest << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Array indices start at 0, not 1.

Comment: And you probably want to start with `highest = temperatures[0];`. Using `temperatures[50]` is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function

```
float average(int days)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= days; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter the temperature for day number " << i << ": ";
        cin >> temperatures[i];
        temptotal += temperatures[i];
//...
```

is already wrong because element `temperatures[0]` will not be uninitialized. You have to write

```
float average(int days)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= days; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter the temperature for day number " << i << ": ";
        cin >> temperatures[i-1];
        temptotal += temperatures[i-1];
//...
```

Or

```
float average(int days)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < days; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter the temperature for day number " << i + 1 << ": ";
        cin >> temperatures[i];
        temptotal += temperatures[i];
//...
```

Functions `highest` and `lowest` are also wrong. For example array `temperatures` has no element with index 50. Moreover the user can enter number of days less than 50. So this statement

```
highest = temperatures[50];
```

is wrong.

The functions can be written like this function definition

```
void highest( int days )
{
    int highest = temperatures[0];

    for ( int count = 1; count < days; count++ )
    {
        if ( highest < temperatures[count] ) highest = temperatures[count];
    }

    cout << "The highest temperature is: " << highest << endl;
}
```

Take into acccount that there are standard algorithms `std::max_element`, `std::min_element`, `std::minmax_element` declared in header `<algorithm>` that can be used instead of your functions.

For example function highest can be defined with using standard algorithm `std::max_element` the following way

```
#include <algorithm>

//...

void highest( int days )
{

    cout << "The highest temperature is: " 
         << *std::max_element( temperatures, temperatures + days )
         << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Array indices start with a 0
2. Place the cout statements outside the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Array indices start with 0 but your loops start at 1. For your loop over days, for instance, this will iterate over the full range:

```
for (int i = 0; i < days; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Arrays are indexed from 0 to n-1**, where `n` is the total number of entries in the array.  You started the count at 1 in your loop when you should start at 0.  If the user entered 50 values, you would have had an out-of-bounds access.

The correction should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < days; i++)
```

Then in your output statement, it should be:

```
cout << "Enter the temperature for day number " << i+1 << ": ";
```

The other issue is your `highest` function.  The issue are a few things:

1. You declared the local variable `highest` as an `int`.  It should be a `float` to match the type used in the `temperature` array.
2. You should set highest to a very small value, smaller than any you would expect.  Or better yet, set it to the first `temperature` entry before the loop, and start the loop from the second entry.
3. You named your local variable `highest`, but your function name is also `highest`.  This will lead to confusion when someone else looks at your code.

---

If you're interested in another solution, the following computes the highest:

```
#include <algorithm>
//...
void highest(int days)
{
    float theHighest = *std::max_element(temperatures, temperatures + days);
    cout << "The highest temperature is: " << theHighest << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A little better version  from the function 'highest':

```
void highest(int days)
{
    if (days < 1)
    {
        cout << "No temperatures" << endl;
    }

    double highest = temperatures[0];

    for (int count = 1; count < days; count++)
    {
        if (temperatures[count] > highest)
        {
            highest = temperatures[count];
        }
    }

    cout << "The highest temperature is: " << temperatures[highest_index] << endl;
}
```

All arrays in C++ starting with index 0. In this implementation this point is considered by using the first element (index 0) as thie first highest value. After that the loop has only to deal with the rest, begining at index 1.

The variable 'highest' **must** be from the type double. Otherwise you may get wrong results, because the highest is a little lower than the real highest due to generaly rounding down (double to int). The next comparison may be assigned even if it is a little lower.